# When toggling a set of tabs, why doesn't content re-appear on click?

Tags: javascript, html, css

In the snippet below, I'm trying to toggle between two sets of content on the page. The page initializes with the content intended, but when I click on the other tab, the respective content doesn't show. And if I click on the first tab, that content is gone as well.

**How do I properly toggle the content without it disappearing?**

```js
    let dropdown = document.querySelector('.dropdown-select');
    let dropdownItem = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-select .menu li');

    dropdown.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      if (dropdown.classList.contains('closed')) {
        dropdown.classList.remove('closed');
        dropdown.classList.add('open');
      } else {
        dropdown.classList.add('closed');
        dropdown.classList.remove('open');
      }
    });

    for (let i = 0; i < dropdownItem.length; i++) {
      dropdownItem[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
        let dropdownItemClicked = document.querySelector('.menu li.active');
        if (dropdownItemClicked) dropdownItemClicked.classList.remove('active');
        dropdownItem[i].classList.add('active');
      })
    }

    const options = document.querySelectorAll('.menu li')

    const results = document.querySelectorAll('.tabbed-content div')
    options.forEach(e => e.addEventListener('click', function () {
      results.forEach(f => f.style.display = f.id == e.dataset.target ? "block" : "none")
    }));
```

```css
.dropdown-select {
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-top: 1px solid #E0E5EC;
  width: 100%;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .dropdown-select {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: default;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E0E5EC;
    height: 3.75rem;
  }
}
.dropdown-select.open {
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 24px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .dropdown-select.open {
    box-shadow: unset;
  }
}
.dropdown-select__title {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding-top: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #E0E5EC;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .dropdown-select__title {
    border-bottom: unset;
  }
}
.dropdown-select__title h6 {
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  line-height: 0.75rem;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.dropdown-select__title img {
  width: 1.312rem;
  height: 0.656rem;
  margin-left: auto;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .dropdown-select__title img {
    display: none;
  }
}
.dropdown-select ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.dropdown-select .menu li {
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  padding: 1rem 0;
  font-weight: 800;
  color: #6D7582;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .dropdown-select .menu li {
    padding: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .dropdown-select .menu li:first-child {
    margin-right: 2rem;
  }
}
.dropdown-select .menu li.active {
  color: #005fec;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .dropdown-select .menu li.active {
    border-bottom: 4px solid #005fec;
  }
}
.dropdown-select__title,
.dropdown-select .menu {
  padding-left: 1.25rem;
  padding-right: 1.25rem;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .dropdown-select__title,
.dropdown-select .menu {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    margin-right: 3.875rem;
  }
}
.dropdown-select.closed .menu {
  height: 0;
}
.dropdown-select.closed img {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.tabbed-content {
  padding-left: 1.25rem;
  padding-right: 1.25rem;
}
.tabbed-content .release {
  display: none;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
  .tabbed-content {
    padding-left: 1.25rem;
    padding-right: 1.25rem;
  }
}
```

```html
  <main>
    <div class="dropdown-select closed">
      <div class="dropdown-select__title">
        <h6>Other Releases</h6>
        <img src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/24/25/25243.png" alt="down caret ">
      </div>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li data-target="fall21" class="active">Fall 2021</li>
        <li data-target="summer21">Summer 2021</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <h6 class="intro kicker kicker--bold">Product Releases</h6>

    <div class="tabbed-content">
      <div id="fall21" class="release" style="display: block;">
        <div class="page-hero">
          <h2>Fall 2021</h2>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div id="summer21" class="release">
        <div class="page-hero">
          <h2>Summer 2021</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fixed you snippet.

You just had on error on the selector of this line : `const results = document.querySelectorAll('.tabbed-content div')`

You need to add `>` to select only **the direct childs** of the `.tabbed-content`
or it will select **all the div inside it**.

So it will be this line : `const results = document.querySelectorAll('.tabbed-content > div'`

```js
let dropdown = document.querySelector('.dropdown-select');
    let dropdownItem = document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-select .menu li');

    dropdown.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      if (dropdown.classList.contains('closed')) {
        dropdown.classList.remove('closed');
        dropdown.classList.add('open');
      } else {
        dropdown.classList.add('closed');
        dropdown.classList.remove('open');
      }
    });

    for (let i = 0; i < dropdownItem.length; i++) {
      dropdownItem[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
        let dropdownItemClicked = document.querySelector('.menu li.active');
        if (dropdownItemClicked) dropdownItemClicked.classList.remove('active');
        dropdownItem[i].classList.add('active');
      })
    }

    const options = document.querySelectorAll('.menu li')

    const results = document.querySelectorAll('.tabbed-content > div')
    options.forEach(e => e.addEventListener('click', function () {
      results.forEach(f => f.style.display = f.id == e.dataset.target ? "block" : "none")
    }));
```

```css
.dropdown-select {
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
  overflow: hidden;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-top: 1px solid #E0E5EC;
  width: 100%;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .dropdown-select {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: default;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E0E5EC;
    height: 3.75rem;
  }
}
.dropdown-select.open {
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 24px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .dropdown-select.open {
    box-shadow: unset;
  }
}
.dropdown-select__title {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding-top: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #E0E5EC;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .dropdown-select__title {
    border-bottom: unset;
  }
}
.dropdown-select__title h6 {
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  line-height: 0.75rem;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.dropdown-select__title img {
  width: 1.312rem;
  height: 0.656rem;
  margin-left: auto;
  transition: all 0.2s ease;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .dropdown-select__title img {
    display: none;
  }
}
.dropdown-select ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.dropdown-select .menu li {
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  padding: 1rem 0;
  font-weight: 800;
  color: #6D7582;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .dropdown-select .menu li {
    padding: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .dropdown-select .menu li:first-child {
    margin-right: 2rem;
  }
}
.dropdown-select .menu li.active {
  color: #005fec;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .dropdown-select .menu li.active {
    border-bottom: 4px solid #005fec;
  }
}
.dropdown-select__title,
.dropdown-select .menu {
  padding-left: 1.25rem;
  padding-right: 1.25rem;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .dropdown-select__title,
.dropdown-select .menu {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    margin-right: 3.875rem;
  }
}
.dropdown-select.closed .menu {
  height: 0;
}
.dropdown-select.closed img {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.tabbed-content {
  padding-left: 1.25rem;
  padding-right: 1.25rem;
}
.tabbed-content .release {
  display: none;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
  .tabbed-content {
    padding-left: 1.25rem;
    padding-right: 1.25rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<main>
    <div class="dropdown-select closed">
      <div class="dropdown-select__title">
        <h6>Other Releases</h6>
        <img src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/24/25/25243.png" alt="down caret ">
      </div>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li data-target="fall21" class="active">Fall 2021</li>
        <li data-target="summer21">Summer 2021</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <h6 class="intro kicker kicker--bold">Product Releases</h6>

    <div class="tabbed-content">
      <div id="fall21" class="release" style="display: block;">
        <div class="page-hero">
          <h2>Fall 2021</h2>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div id="summer21" class="release">
        <div class="page-hero">
          <h2>Summer 2021</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
```

Comment: That was something I thought I'd tried. Thanks!